# ipython notebook: socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known

Tags: python, ipython, anaconda

I'm running Mac OS X 10.10.3 and everything Python-related is set up using Anaconda with Python 3.  I am using IPython 3.0.0 and Python 3.4.3.  Here is the error message that keeps coming up when I try to run the `ipython notebook` command:

```
shermmac:~ brandonsherman$ ipython notebook
[I 16:40:57.969 NotebookApp] Using existing profile dir: '/Users/brandonsherman/.ipython/profile_default'
[I 16:40:57.974 NotebookApp] Using MathJax from CDN: https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/brandonsherman/anaconda/bin/ipython", line 6, in <module>
    sys.exit(start_ipython())
  File "/Users/brandonsherman/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 120, in start_ipython
    return launch_new_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/brandonsherman/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 573, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in initialize
  File "/Users/brandonsherman/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 75, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/brandonsherman/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/terminal/ipapp.py", line 321, in initialize
    super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).initialize(argv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in initialize
  File "/Users/brandonsherman/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 75, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/brandonsherman/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/core/application.py", line 369, in initialize
    self.parse_command_line(argv)
  File "/Users/brandonsherman/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/terminal/ipapp.py", line 316, in parse_command_line
    return super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).parse_command_line(argv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in parse_command_line
  File "/Users/brandonsherman/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 75, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/brandonsherman/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 471, in parse_command_line
    return self.initialize_subcommand(subc, subargv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in initialize_subcommand
  File "/Users/brandonsherman/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 75, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/brandonsherman/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 409, in initialize_subcommand
    self.subapp.initialize(argv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in initialize
  File "/Users/brandonsherman/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 75, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/brandonsherman/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/html/notebookapp.py", line 980, in initialize
    self.init_webapp()
  File "/Users/brandonsherman/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/html/notebookapp.py", line 842, in init_webapp
    self.http_server.listen(port, self.ip)
  File "/Users/brandonsherman/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tornado/tcpserver.py", line 125, in listen
    sockets = bind_sockets(port, address=address)
  File "/Users/brandonsherman/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tornado/netutil.py", line 106, in bind_sockets
    0, flags)):
  File "/Users/brandonsherman/anaconda/lib/python3.4/socket.py", line 533, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known

If you suspect this is an IPython bug, please report it at:
    https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues
or send an email to the mailing list at ipython-dev@scipy.org

You can print a more detailed traceback right now with "%tb", or use "%debug"
to interactively debug it.

Extra-detailed tracebacks for bug-reporting purposes can be enabled via:
    c.Application.verbose_crash=True
```

Comment: It fails when it tries to bind the port where you cannot connect to IPython Notebook with your browser. Check that you don't have changed Notebook network settings. Check that you don't have firewall or similar blocking the networ.

Comment: This is odd.  I didn't change settings and didn't reboot, and it's suddenly working again.  Should I close the question, or leave it open in case someone else figures out a solution in the future?

Comment: You can answer your own question - maybe other people have the same question later. What I suspect is that the operating system had some kind of network error and it recovered from it itself.